# Grails and Apache Shiro - How to implement doUpdatePassword and doResetPassword closures

Tags: grails, shiro

I'm developing a Grails app and I'm using Shiro to handle the access security. I think my app is now secured but there are some missing features. The generated password is too hard to remember so it's necessary a view to change the generated (current) password to a personalized one, an update password operation must be implemented, however there's a reference in the updatePassword.gsp file to the doUpdatePassword closure but it's not implemented. So how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess I am missing some info... which plugin do you use - I can't find a `updatePassword.gsp`...